# Exist a way to make gTLD servers update its NS records for a given domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, whois, domain-registrar, ns-record, soa-record

I changed the DNS servers for a given domain and still days after that change gTLD continue replying a set of NS records that include the old NS entries.

```
dig @g.gtld-servers.net. example.com ns
```

return six records, four are the new records and correct NS records for example.com and two are the oldest and staled NS records for that domain.

The registrar is *DNC Holdings, Inc.* and when I query its WHOIS service with:

```
whois example.com -h  whois.directnic.com
```

the NS listed are correct, but if I run:

```
whois example.com
```

the first part of the reply show 6 NS records, including the two old NS records but in the last part of the reply (that one I suppose is returned by the whois.directnic.com server) just the 4 and correct NS records.

The effect of this situations is that when I add a record to the new NSs and to the old NSs and execute a query again publics DNS like 8.8.8.8, the returned value is the value I set on the old NSs.

How can I solve this problem? Exist a way to ask gTLD domains to purge its cache?

**EDIT**

Both, old and new NS set respond with the correct four records to the query like `dig @NameServerOldOrNew example.com`

Comment: 1. WHOIS information is informational. It has no real bearing on resolution of your domain. 2. Have you actually queried for your name servers at the parent gTLD? Try the DNS delegation test here as well - http://www.simpledns.com/lookup-dg.aspx 3. Have you spoken to the Registrar, seeing as they're ultimately responsible? 4. What is the real domain name? Telling us can help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @joeqwerty! I know about the roll of WHOIS, just mention it as a prove that registrar config is good, cos most registrars have its whois database is in sync with whatever tools they provide to change NS records. 2. That tools is precisely what `dig @g.gtld-servers.net. MYDOMAON.COM ns` does.The result I got with the web you point me is the same,six NS records. 3. Is the only thing that remain, but is not simple cos domain was registered by another company than the company I'm supporting,even this last company "own" the domain 4. I will message you privately with the name.

Comment: Ups, I just realize that private message is not available here. I can't said what domain is cos company policy.

Answer (score 1):

http://intodns.com/ is your friend :)

if i understand correctly, your authoritative nameservers are returning six NS records (should be four)

most likely, the issue is the new NS entries were simply added to existing zone file (instead of replacing the two existing ones)

you can verify what your auth ns's are erroneously returning six records by querying each one:

> dig @authoritativeNS1 YOURDOMAIN.COM NS

if this is the issue, the fix is to remove the 2 old NS entries from zone file.

Comment: Thanks @nandoP for your reply. My authoritative NS is replying just four DNS, I just forgot mention in my question that.